# In place update in azure: server 2019 -> 2022, cannot keep apps and files

Tags: upgrade, windows-server-2022, azure-vm

I have a windows server 2019 (datacenter) from azure. i'm trying to in-place update it to server 2022 as outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade

`.\setup.exe /auto upgrade /dynamicupdate disable`

After starting setup, i select "windows datacenter (desktop experience)". In the next step, i'm supposed to be able to select what i want to keep. (i want to keep everything.). However, there is no such step. Setup directly goes to the "install" part and never asks, what i want to keep.

When i select "windows 2022 standard (desktop)", the step with the question comes up, but the options to keep stuff are disabled.

How can i inplace upgrade my vm to 2022 and still keep my apps and settings?

Comment: Are all the latest windows updates installed? afaik there was a bug which was fixed in one of the later updates.

Comment: Yes, i just checked and all updates have been installed.